# Data Structure to hold path name of files ending with a particular extension

Tags: data-structures, filesystems

I have designed a multi-threaded application which crawls a users file-system for files ending with a particular extension (.mp3/.wav). The crawl, even though multi-threaded, takes a long time and it would be easy to store the full path-names of these files on secondary storage for efficient look-up and not perform the crawl every time the application starts. Moreover, I need the path-names to search for files.

How should I store the path-names on disk? Which data structure should I use to store these path-names such that when the application loads I can pull the data structure file from disk, parse the contents and build a nice look up table in memory for efficient search and file manipulation (insert, delete)?

I was thinking of storing the entire data structure(tree or hash map) with the path names as a .txt file such that when the application loads it will read and parse the .txt file and load the data structure in memory. The data structure I feel would be a dictionary data structure such as a balanced tree (AVL, B tree or red-black tree)? If tree, how should I format the data and store the tree on disk? Thanks in advance for your answers! Sorry for the long post!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just storing the file pathnames, then it would be good to write all the file paths to a text file. When the application loads up, you can read the file and store all the paths in a set.